Issue with Plotting a Reciprocal Function on HTML5 Canvas
I'm currently developing a function plotting application using HTML Canvas and JavaScript. The application is designed to plot various mathematical functions entered by the user. It handles linear functions (like y=x and y=x+2) perfectly, rendering them correctly on the canvas.
However, I'm encountering a specific issue with reciprocal functions, particularly functions like y=2/x. When I try to plot this type of function, the canvas remains blank and doesn't show any error messages or logs in the console.
Here's a snippet of my code that handles the plotting:


var canvas = document.getElementById('plotCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var startX = -20;
var endX = 20;
var scaleFactor = 25;
var epsilon = 0.0001; // A small number close to zero


ctx.beginPath();
for (var x = startX + 0.01; x <= endX; x += 0.01) {
  xP = (x - startX) * (canvas.width / (endX - startX));
  let y = 2/x
  yP = canvas.height / 2 - y * scaleFactor

  if (xP > -canvas.width && yP > -canvas.height && xP < canvas.width && yP < canvas.height) {
    ctx.lineTo(xP, yP);
  } else {
    ctx.moveTo(xP, yP)
  }
}




ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="plotCanvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</body>
</html>



I think the problem is because when x = 0, it's going to infinity, and thats not possible to draw.
How can I fix this?

If you log 2 / x to the console you'll see output like this: 0.10256410256409952. The problem is therefore not that the line isn't being rendered, but instead that the output is such a low value it's impossible to see it above the lower axis line. I'd suggest you amend your logic to automatically scale the y axis to the given range of output values.

How can I fix this?

You could sort all your y-values and find the min and max for which a certain percentile of the values will be included.
Note that this is some overhead if you choose a large range or a very small delta x.
Here's an example where I:

First calculate the (x,y) points,
Then calculate the min and max y values that include 98% of the points,
Then render each points by scaling them from the (x,y) space to the canvas dimensions



const cvs = document.getElementById('plotCanvas');
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

const minX = -20;
const maxX = 20;
const dx = 0.1;

const points = graph(
  x => 2 / x,
  minX,
  maxX,
  dx
);

const yRange = range(0.01, 0.99, points.map(p => p.y));

ctx.beginPath();
for (const { x, y, i } of points) {
  
  const px = scale(x, minX, maxX, 0, cvs.width);
  const py = scale(y, yRange.max, yRange.min, 0, cvs.height);

  const prev = points[i - 1];
  
  // Do not draw lines to/from (-)Infinity
  if (
    !prev ||
    y === Infinity ||
    y === -Infinity ||
    prev.y === Infinity ||
    prev.y === -Infinity) {
    ctx.moveTo(px, py);
  } else {
    ctx.lineTo(px, py);
  }

}


ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
ctx.stroke();

function scale(from, minFrom, maxFrom, minTo, maxTo) {
  const pFrom = (from - minFrom) / (maxFrom - minFrom);
  return minTo + (maxTo - minTo) * pFrom;
}

function graph(
  f,
  startX = -20,
  endX = 20,
  dx = 0.1,
) {
  const points = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < (endX - startX) / dx; i += 1) {
    const x = startX + i * dx;
    const y = f(x)
    points.push({ x, y, i });
  }
  
  return points;
}

function range(fromP, toP, values) {
  const p0 = Math.round(values.length * fromP);
  const p1 = Math.round(values.length * toP);
  
  const s = Array.from(values).sort((a,b) => b - a);
  
  return { min: s[p0], max: s[p1] };
}
<canvas id="plotCanvas" width="400" height="300" style="border: 1px solid black"></canvas>




But then I have the problem with the Linie in the Middle. How can I fix that?

I added a check that ensures no lines are drawn to Infinity (which will be what JS returns when dividing by 0)

Note that that's not a perfect approach; it only works if your steps include the exact x=0 case (for this formula)
